# Owl carousel prev next button not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using owl carousel to display product.The problem is that next and previous buttons are not showing up.

Here are the files I have included

1. owl.carousel.min.css
2. owl.theme.default.min.css
3. owl.carousal.min

In main.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   $('.owl-carousel-featured-product').owlCarousel({
loop:true,
margin:10,
nav:true,
dots:false,
items:4,
responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1
    },
    600:{
        items:3
    },
    1000:{
        items:5
    }
}
});
});
```

Below is generated HTML

```
<div class="owl-carousel-featured-product  featured-product"> 
  <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
  <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 7410px; left: 0px; display:    block;">
   <div class="owl-item" style="width: 285px;">
      <div class="productslide">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  <div class="owl-controls clickable">
     <div class="owl-pagination">
         <div class="owl-page active">
           <span class=""></span>
           </div>
         <div class="owl-page">
            <span class=""></span>
         </div>
        <div class="owl-page">
         <span class=""></span>
       </div>
       <div class="owl-page">
         <span class=""></span>
       </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Although the nav:true option is set and still not showing up the prev & Next button html is not rendered.

Comment: nav:true work  on version 2 and above, you can  try navigation:true

and if the number of item less in the crousel defined number for specific view-port ,  in this case the button also hidden

Comment: Accidently I commented the owl.carousal.min.js file :( . Now everything is working.

Comment: there is a typo in the name, right?